# Bizarre network connection complication, no internet access

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, home-networking, internet-connection, network-adapter

Briefly - Yellow triangle /!\ No internet connection.

Not-so-briefly The network can not obtain network settings from the router (whether it is my home router or phone on tethering) instead, it uses local IP. According to ipconfig, it doesn't have gateway at all.

Exhaustively: I am using Tenda 300Mbs Wireless N USB Adapter on my asrock PC By measuring one of the PSU's connectors with evidently trash multimeter, I caused a short, forcing the PSU to shut down in order to prevent any further damage. Since then, the wifi problem occurred. Even if the PSU failed to prevent damage, everything appears to be working normally. The USB ports work, I can connect my mobile phone as a storage device or as a lan card with usb mode tethering.. no kernel panics, no problems in task manager, nothing suspicious. The Tenda works too, as I mentioned, just not on my PC.

I also tried to reinstall USB drivers, Tenda software + drivers, rollback system back when it had no problems, disable firewall, run in safe mode, restart bios settings, restart router, restart Tenda, swap usb ports (tried also those on the pc case, not only those on the motherboard) - nothing.

What the hell? The only logical thing to take into consideration is if the wireless usb multidirectional transfer protocols depend on 3rd party hardware that fails, hiding it from the task manager. But that sounds like.. like a 5 years old trying to be google engineer sort of jabbling.

The ISPs also said "it's dead end to us, ktnxbye". What could possible cause this odd problem ?
[image]

Comment: You may of fried the wifi - Can you try connecting with an RJ45 cable direct to the router? - Also try USB cable from phone tethering. Do either of those methods give you IP?

Comment: I assume you tldr'ed. I mentioned that tethering by virtue of USB works, i.e gives me IP also how could I fried the wifi considering the fact it is a flash drive adapter that works on other PC(s) ?

Comment: Have you tried a cabled connection? When you say it gives you IP - It doesn't according to the screenshot. 169.254.x.x is a 'Link local' address which you get when it cannot communicate.

Comment: @JohnnyVegas For the USB tethering connection I was talking about - it gives me ip considering the fact I have internet with it. For the wifi, as I said in the description, it does not. Also I really can not check cable connection.

Comment: It's a really odd one - Only thing I can think of is to get a USB power tester to check if the voltages on the ports are ok. Sorry I can't help further, and sorry for not reading your question accurately.

Comment: I measured it with multimeter and it outputs 5V as it should. Very odd.

Comment: You need to check the amperage as well - Also, try creating a new user with admin privileges and test the USB wifi from there

Comment: @JohnnyVegas What about installing Debian? ..testing from there

Comment: Also how the amperage should be?

Comment: Well worth trying debian - can't hurt. Amperage should be no more than 500ma